Is admin-ajax.php loading issue in Wordpress web hosts fault?
I can't figure out why admin-ajax.php causes my WordPress website to freeze.
network status of admin-ajax.php
The website freezes when working inside the admin dashboard after a certain number of editing activities. Admin-ajax.php just goes to pending until it reaches the timeout limit and then repeats the same until I exit all the tabs related to that website. The loading never stops!
No error logs in WP or inside web hosting.
The website is NEVER down, I can access it through a different browser, mobile and even Chrome Incognito. It is just that I am not able to access any page of the website in the same browser while the tab where admin-ajax.php is loading is open. If I close every page and wait a couple of minutes everything goes back to normal, I can open any page in the same browser where there was a crash.
For example if I open a list of all Woocommerce products, Wordpress heartbeat feature automatically sends admin-ajax requests, after a couple of requests I open a new tab and work on the website and for example sometimes after a couple of minutes of working and sometimes after 15 minutes it freezes while editing menus or inside customizer.
The WordPress installation is fresh, installed through Softaculous on shared hosting. The theme is Astra, with WooCommerce and the Loginizer plugin. Nothing custom, not even a child theme.
Tried everything: changing PHP file version, increasing PHP timeout limit, deactivating ModSecurity, new installation of plugins, new installation of complete WP, different browser, caching plugins, disabling heartbeat control...
Same setup on a different host with the same computer, and can't replicate the issue.
Also sometimes when it freezes and I let it load for a couple of minutes it unfreezes on its own. Take a look at the screenshot:
Screenshot of network processes
Has anyone faced the same problem?
Do you think this issue is related to the web hosting provider?

Avast antivirus was causing the problem
